# RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am having an issue with loading some assets in production mode (Ubuntu 14.04).
I am currently running ruby with passenger and apache in production mode, but when loading the website on `http://address/site` I get some errors

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/manifest.css"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/manifest.js")
```

I tried already to use precompile assets (even if apache should serve static file without any particular issue)

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

as well as add to production.rb

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

OR

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Unfortunately, the results are exactly the same. 
The weird thing for me is that If instead I go to `http://website:3000` everything works perfectly (css and js are there etc.)..

Any ideas?

### **EDIT**:

Adding `config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']`in `initializers/assets.rb` together with `config.serve_static_files = true` in `production.rb` solved some of the problems.
Now it correctly load the js/css but not the svg/ttf. I tried to add those too, as in:

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.svg', '*.ttf', '*.gif']
```

but without success.

The problem I see is that it try to load the resource from `http://website/assets/resource.svg` , while they are in `http://website/vocab/assets/resource.svg`

I also change the owner of http://website/vocab (`chown -R www-data:www-data vocab/`)to www-data, so everything should be readable by Apache.

**Added resource** 
Content of Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# TODO: The following dependencies could be included by the "gemspec" command.
# There is only one problem: gemspec puts the dependencies automatically to a
# group (:development by default). This is not what we need.
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.8'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'kaminari-bootstrap', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'authlogic', '~> 3.4.2'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10.0'
gem 'iq_rdf', '>= 0.1.15'
gem 'iq_triplestorage'
gem 'json'
gem 'rails_autolink'
gem 'faraday', '0.9.0'
gem 'faraday_middleware'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.0'
gem 'linkeddata', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap_form', '~> 2.2.0'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'apipie-rails', '~> 0.3.5'
gem 'maruku', require: false
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 6.5.1.1'
gem "passenger", ">= 5.0.25", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"

# database adapters
# comment out those you do don't need or use a different Gemfile
#gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.13'
gem 'sqlite3'
#gem 'pg'

group :development do
  gem 'view_marker'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'awesome_print'

  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '0.7.3.pre1'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'pry-byebug', '~> 1.1.2', platforms: :ruby_20
  gem 'quiet_assets'

  platforms :ruby do
    gem 'hirb-unicode'
    gem 'cane'
  end

  platforms :jruby do
    gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
    gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
    gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', '~> 1.3.13'
  end
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.0'
  gem 'poltergeist', '~> 1.6.0'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'simplecov'
end

group :production do
end

group :heroku do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and content of Virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html/Skosmos>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.4/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.4
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby2.4
   </IfModule>

    ServerName website.fr/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 Alias vocab/ /var/www/html/vocab/public
    <Location /vocab>
        PassengerBaseURI /vocab
        PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/vocab/

    </Location>
    <Directory /var/www/html/vocab/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Try adding this `config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']` in `initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: Thanks! I tried and it actually resolve some of the issue, but not completely. I updated the EDIT above to reflect the changes

Comment: Keep `config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']` and try `config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/` for svg/ttf

Comment: done, restart passenger and nothing changed :\

Answer (score 0):

If you work on Windows, try to install and add this gem to Gemfile:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

But only this version..

Comment: Generally lack of some gems causes assets load errors like this. Specially, if the projects works regularly on "development mode" and not working on "production mode".. 
If you add your Gemfile i will compare it with my project's Gemfile which works on linux. So, we'll be sure, this error not related with gem requirements. :)

Comment: Added in the main post :)